# Visual Studio 2012 AsConfigured build option

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, azure-devops

I'm looking for a way to change the Build Output Location setting for my project which uses Visual Studio Team Services. I found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647547.aspx#output) which seems to specify an option available in Visual Studio 2013, but I don't see the same option in 2012 and don't want to install 2013 yet.

Can someone help me find how to change this setting to "AsConfigured"?

-Edit-
I installed Visual Studio 2013 and still can't find the setting.

In Visual Studio 2013:
1) Team Explorer -> Builds -> Locate build definition in All Build Definitions -> Right click to edit the definition.
2) Build Definition -> Process tab -> **No "Build Output Location" setting can be found.**

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Are you using the hosted build controller or a local one?

Comment: I'm using the hosted build controller at the moment. I admit I have very little build experience, so I'd like to keep things are simple as possible.

Comment: That option is a 2013 feature, you're not going to get it in 2012.

Comment: OK well I installed VS 2013 Professional and I still don't see the feature. Has anyone used it or can help me find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the option you're looking for is "Solution specific build outputs". It is on the Git build process template that the option is called "Build Output Location".

Comment: I see the option now. Thanks very much for the help. I'm at home now but only have VS 2012, so the option is disabled for me.